# Proto Repeated Custom Item Syntax

Tags: rust, protocol-buffers

I came across this code:

```proto
message MapTaskAssignment {
  uint32 task = 1;
  uint32 worker_id = 2;
}

message GetTaskReply {
  ...
  repeated MapTaskAssignment map_task_assignments = 10;
}
```

I've seen `repeated string` before. But what does it mean when the repeated item is another proto object (`repeated MapTaskAssignment`)? How does it work and how can I access the fields inside?

Edit:
Specifically, using rust, what type does `repeated MapTaskAssignment` convert to? is it a `Vec` of `struct MapTaskAssignment`?

Answer (score 0):

In the same manner `RepeatedField` is defined in [google/protobuf/repeated_field.h](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.repeated_field), [prost](https://docs.rs/prost/0.11.3/prost/#field-modifiers) - Protocol Buffers implementation for Rust defines `repeated`:   `Vec<T>`.

For your sample Protocol Buffers definition [tonic-build](https://docs.rs/tonic-build/latest/tonic_build/) would create

```
pub struct MapTaskAssignment {
    #[prost(uint32, tag = "1")]
    pub task: u32,
    #[prost(uint32, tag = "2")]
    pub worker_id: u32,
}

pub struct GetTaskReply {
    #[prost(message, repeated, tag = "10")]
    pub map_task_assignments: ::prost::alloc::vec::Vec<MapTaskAssignment>,
}
```